# How can I validate the XML document in a SAXParser without having to use an XMLReader?

Tags: java, xml, xerces, xml-validation

I want to create a `SAXParser` which validates, but it seems the only way is either to create an `XMLReader` and use `setErrorHandler()` or let the `ContentHandler` in `SAXParser.parse()` also implement `ErrorHandler`.

Am I missing something? All I want to do is create a validating `SAXParser` like this:

```
private SAXParser createParser(final boolean validateXML) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
  final SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

  factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
  factory.setValidating(validateXML);
  factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", validateXML);

  SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

  Assert.assertNotNull("Checking parser exists", parser);
  Assert.assertEquals("Checking validation", validateXML, parser.isValidating());
  Assert.assertTrue("Checking namespace awareness", parser.isNamespaceAware());
  return parser;
}
```

I'm using Xerces 2.9.1

Thanks for any hints!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand, but is this a solution for you? -->
[Xerces2 XSD Validation with SAXParser](http://www.herongyang.com/XML-Schema/Xerces2-XSD-Validation-with-SAXParser.html)

Comment: Unfortunately no, since from my experience the SAXParser itself doesn't validate. You have to parse an XML document and add an ErrorHandler to discover whether the XML is valid or invalid. So, even though the SAXParser itself tells you it's validating, it actually isn't, it's only the ContentHandler/ErrorHandler that makes the difference.

At least that's what I experienced... It would be nice to be proven wrong  :-)